# Leer salida de una llamada SOAP

Tags: php, xml, soap

Tengo un array php que envío a un servicio SOAP, pero el servicio me devuelve un error

```
$params = ["key1"=>"value 1", "key2" => "value 2"];
$soap = new SoapClient($url, ["trace"=>true]);
$data = $soap->metodo($params);
```

Esta operación me devuelve:

> Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (2, 461). ---> The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value.

Entendiendo que el mensaje indica que hay un error en el formato XML por lo que quiero es validar manualmente ese XML resultante que se envía al servicio SOAP.

¿Como puedo generar una salida del XML resultante que es enviado al servicio? De ser posible quisiera obtenerla antes de enviarla al servicio SOAP para poderla validar.
He tratado de hacer un "trace" en "SoapClient" pero al parecer, debido a que el proceso aborta su ejecusión .. no puedo obtener ningún otro dato del proceso que me sirva para obtener el XML resultante que se envía al servicio.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// below $option=array('trace',1);
// correct one is below
$option=array('trace'=>1);

$client=new SoapClient('some.wsdl',$option);

try{
  $client->aMethodAtRemote();
}catch(SoapFault $fault){
  // <xmp> tag displays xml output in html
  echo 'Request : <br/><xmp>',
  $client->__getLastRequest(),
  '</xmp><br/><br/> Error Message : <br/>',
  $fault->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Échale un ojo a la documentación de SoapClient.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/soapclient.getlastrequest.php

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, pero aun no logro dar con una solución, implementando la solución sugerida obtengo una respuesta del servidor, pero no es la que espero. el servidor responde:  Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (2, 461). ---> The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value.....  Pero lo que yo quiero es auditar lo que estoy enviando, pues según se ve en la respuesta del servidor, al parecer hay errores en el XML resultante que envío. Luego lo que quiero es visualizar ese XML de ser posible antes de enviarlo al servicio SOAP..  Gracias

Comment: Bien .. al final usé la solución propuesta pero en vez de apuntarla al servicio SOAP remoto ... lo hice a una dirección local al propio servidor de mi aplicación ... y listo ... ahí si tuve mis respuestas !!!